# Lithium Couchdb find:all

Tags: php, couchdb, lithium

I started working on lithium and couchdb using their blog tutorial.
One thing i noticed is that find:all is not working properly:
Posts:find('all', array('conditions' => array('title' => 'title'))
The conditions are not working. It all queries the documents and designs.
Any experience about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB doesn't support ad-hoc queries (i.e. queries with arbitrary conditions). You need to create a view and query that.

Comment: Hi Nate, Thanks for your answer, If couchdb doesnt support ad-hoc queries does it mean Lithium relationships is not working as well?

Comment: Lithium does not support relationships for CouchDB.